# Видеоплеер для DTS фильмов

Tags: видео, кодек

Имеется 5.1 аудиосистема с ресивером *AVR-1510S*, подключенная к *ПК* через *HDMI*.

Есть фильмы с многоканальными дорожками. Не могу найти нормальный плеер. Пробовал на эталонном семпле, скачанного с dts сайта:

1. *Windows Media Player* - играет хорошо, но есть проблемы с *BD*-фильмами.
2. *Media Player Classic* - играет без тыловых колонок, не все форматы ест нормально.
3. *VLC* - вообще звук ни как не выводил ни с тестового, ни с других dts файлов.
4. *KMPlayer* - звук хорошо, а вот видео с *БД* диска не выводил. Т.е. звук есть, а видео нет.

Посоветуйте.

Comment: Что на счет Quick Time Player?

Comment: не помог, тоже что и с MPC было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему перенастройкой кодеков и KMPlayer-а.